# Given inradius and half of one side, need to find the area of Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

[image]

△ABC is a traingle, where O is the incentre and OD is perpendicular to AB. By definition, <OAC = < OAD = θ and < OBC = < OBD =  α. Given OD = 3 and BD = 4. The problem is to find the area of △ABC.

My approach : We know the area of a triangle is inradius (r) multiplied with the semicentre (s). So, need to find s. Better to get hold of the sides. Construct the necessary lines to get the following diagram.

[image]

We already have r = 3. Now, s would be s = {(a+b)+(a+4)+(b+4)}/2 = a+b+4.

Now, tan(α) = 3/4. Also, a = 3 tan(θ) and b = 3 tan(π/2-α-θ) = 3 cot(α+θ) = 3/tan(α+θ).

Then, s = a+b+4 = 3 tan(θ) + 3/tan(arctan(3/4)+θ)

No progress furthermore. Can anybody suggest any lead? Or maybe some other way to solve the problem.

Comment: This is not a unique construct and you can have $\triangle ABC$ with different areas where inradius is $3$ and $BD = 4$.

Comment: You sure that the different construction won't have the area? And can this statement be proved?

Comment: Yes I am sure. You can try in Geogebra. You can make an equation and show that different values of $\theta$ lead to different areas whereas $r$ and $BD$ remain $3$ and $4$ resp.

Comment: It seems someone has given me an example of what you mentioned. Thanks mate for the help.

Comment: Subject to the specified conditions, the least possible area for triangle $ABC$ is $48$, which is realized when
$$
AB=10,\;BC=10,\;CA=12
$$
and as g.kov's answer illustrates, the area for a qualifying triangle can be made arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unique triangle can not be defined by given data,
and the area can be made infinitely big:

[image]